# Find a string in a list using groovy collection

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to find a string in a list using Groovy

Here is my working code:

```
for(Export e : lstexport) {
    if(e.keyValue.contains("mountain")) {
        return "mountain";
    }
return ""
```

Not working code

```
String str = lstexport.collect{it.keyValue}.contains("mountain").toString() ? "mountain" : ""
```

This is always returning value as `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [find](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
println (['a','b','c'].find{ it == 'c' }​ ?: 'not found')​
```

Try it at https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5146305110212608 .

Comment: @Michael, Its not working .. Here is my code.. lstexport.collect{it.keyValue}[mountain, hill].. If I use lstexport.collect{it.keyValue}.find{ it == "mountain"}.. This is returning null

Comment: Strange. I am not sure this will help, but you can try dropping the collect, like this: `lstexport.find { it.keyValue == 'mountain' }`. Also judging by the code you posted, you don't actually have a list of strings but rather need to  get a `toString()` from the elements of your list, so maybe make this `{ it.keyValue.toString() == 'mountain'}`